# 100% CPU for Docker Container when started via entrypoint

Tags: c++, docker, docker-stack

We have written a small C++ application which mainly does some supervising of other processes via ZeroMQ. So most of the time, the application idles and periodcally sends and receives some requests.

We built a docker image based on `ubuntu` which contains just this application, some dependencies and an `entrypoint.sh`. The entrypoint basically runs as `/bin/bash`, manipulates some configuration files based on environment variables and then starts the application via `exec`.

Now here's the strange part. When we start the application manually without docker, we get a CPU usage of nearly 0%. When we start the same application as docker image, the CPU usage goes up to 100% and blocks exactly one CPU core.

To find out what was happening, we set the entrypoint of our image to `/bin/yes` (just to make sure the container keeps running) and then started a bash inside the running container. From there we started `entrypoint.sh` manually and the CPU again was at 0%.

So we are wondering, what could cause this situation.  Is there anything we need to add to our Dockerfile to prevent this?

---

Here is some output generated with `strace`. I used `strace -p <pid> -f -c` and waited five minutes to collect some insights.

#### 1. Running with `docker run` (100% CPU)

```
strace: Process 12621 attached with 9 threads
strace: [ Process PID=12621 runs in x32 mode. ]
[...]

% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 71.26   17.866443         144    124127           nanosleep
 14.40    3.610578       55547        65        31 futex
 14.07    3.528224        1209      2918           epoll_wait
  0.10    0.024760        4127         6         1 restart_syscall
  0.10    0.024700           0     66479           poll
  0.05    0.011339           4      2902         3 recvfrom
  0.02    0.005517           2      2919           write
  0.01    0.001685           1      2909           read
  0.00    0.000070          70         1         1 connect
  0.00    0.000020          20         1           socket
  0.00    0.000010           1        18           epoll_ctl
  0.00    0.000004           1         6           sendto
  0.00    0.000004           1         4           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpeername
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           setsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getsockopt
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   25.073354                202359        36 total
```

#### 2. Running with a dummy entrypoint and `docker exec` (0% CPU)

```
strace: Process 31394 attached with 9 threads
[...]
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 67.32   12.544007         102    123355           nanosleep
 14.94    2.784310       39216        71        33 futex
 14.01    2.611210         869      3005           epoll_wait
  2.01    0.373797           6     66234           poll
  1.15    0.213487          71      2999           recvfrom
  0.41    0.076113       15223         5         1 restart_syscall
  0.09    0.016295           5      3004           write
  0.08    0.014458           5      3004           read
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   18.633677                201677        34 total
```

Note that in the first case i started `strace` slightly earlier so there are some different calls which can all be traced back to initialization code.

The only difference I could find is the line `Process PID=12621 runs in x32 mode.` when using `docker run`. Could this be an issue?

Also note that in both measurements the total runtime is about 20 seconds while the process was running for five minutes.

---

Some further investigations on the 100% CPU case. I checked the process with `top -H -p <pid>` and only the parent process was using 100% CPU while the child threads were all mostly idling. But when calling `strace -p <pid>` on the parent process I could verify, that the process did not do anything (no output was generated).

So I do have a process which is using one whole core of my CPU doing exactly nothing.

Comment: Attach `strace` to the running command and see which system calls it performs. Compare against a 'native' run. It is probably a small mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Botje. Today I learned you can `strace` into docker processes. I added my strace results to the original question.

Comment: In the docker case I see a `connect` that failed. That sounds like something to investigate. Alternatively, you can try attaching GDB to the process inside Docker to see where it is spending all the CPU time.

Comment: Disclaimer: Colleague of OP here.
As soon as I attach gdb to the process, the CPU usage goes down to 0%. After detaching, it's back to 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out some legacy part of the software was waiting for console input in a while loop:

```
while (!finished) {
  std::cin >> command;
  processCommand(command)
}
```

So this worked fine when running locally and with `docker exec`. But since the executable was started as a docker service, there was no console present. Therefore `std::cin` was non-blocking and returned immediately. This way we created an endless loop without any sleeps which naturally caused a 100% CPU usage.

Thanks to @Botje for guiding us through the debugging process.